# I don't understand how borrowing works

Tags: compilation, rust, borrow-checker

I'm trying to write a kd-tree implementation, but I keep getting the error `cannot move out of borrowed content.`

This is my KDTree struct

```
pub struct KDTree {
    pub bounding_box: Aabb,
    pub axis: Option<Axis>,
    left: Option<Box<KDTree>>,
    right: Option<Box<KDTree>>,
    pub objects: Option<Vec<Box<Geometry>>>,
}
```

This method, however, throws that error.

```
pub fn direct_samples(&self) -> Vec<u32> {
    assert!(self.objects.is_some());
    let mut direct_samples = Vec::new();
    for (i, object) in self.objects
        .expect("Expected tree to have objects")
        .iter()
        .enumerate() {
        if object.material().emittance > 0f32 {
            direct_samples.push(i as u32);
        }
    }
    if self.left.is_some() {
        direct_samples.extend(self.left.unwrap().direct_samples());
    }
    if self.right.is_some() {
        direct_samples.extend(self.right.unwrap().direct_samples());
    }
    direct_samples
}
```

I understand that if I change the parameter to `self` instead of `&self`, it should work, but then when I call it, it gives the error `use of moved value.`

```
pub fn from_objects(objects: Vec<Box<Geometry>>) -> Scene {
    let tree = KDTree::from_objects(objects);

    Scene {
        camera: Camera::new(),
        objects: tree,
        direct_samples: tree.direct_samples(),
    }
}
```

Do I need to implement Copy on my KDTree? Won't this use a lot of cpu/memory to copy the entire thing?

Comment: Aside: `Option<Vec>` seems fishy, a `Vec` can already be empty so wrapping it in an `Option` that you then assert shouldn't exist seems pretty useless. Even if `None` and `Some(empty_vec)` really do mean something different, that's a rather confusing distinction.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason your code requires ownership of the KDTree is because you are calling `Option::expect` and `Option::unwrap`. The docs for these can be found [here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.unwrap).

```
impl<T> Option<T> {
    fn unwrap(self) -> T {
        ...
    }
}
```

So when you are calling unwrap (or expect) the compiler rightly complains that you are taking the elements of your struct by value. To fix this, use the `Option::as_ref` [method](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.as_ref).

```
impl<T> Option<T> {
    fn as_ref(&self) -> Option<&T> {
        ...
    }
}
```

This will turn a reference to an option into an optional reference, which does not require ownership. You can see this in the signature of the function - it takes `&self` rather than `self`.

```
pub fn direct_samples(&self) -> Vec<u32> {
    assert!(self.objects.is_some());
    let mut direct_samples = Vec::new();
    for (i, object) in self.objects.as_ref()
        .expect("Expected tree to have objects")
        .iter()
        .enumerate() {
        if object.material().emittance > 0f32 {
            direct_samples.push(i as u32);
        }
    }
    if self.left.is_some() {
        direct_samples.extend(self.left.as_ref().unwrap().direct_samples());
    }
    if self.right.is_some() {
        direct_samples.extend(self.right.as_ref().unwrap().direct_samples());
    }
    direct_samples
}
```

> Do I need to implement Copy on my KDTree? Won't this use a lot of cpu/memory to copy the entire thing?

You can't implement `Copy` on your `KDTree` because it contains heap-allocated memory (boxes) - `Copy` means that your type can be copied just by copying its bytes, but that can't happen without invalidating single ownership in this case.